# Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget' in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Browser shows failed to compile.
Please help

Error : Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'

HTML code :

```
<div>
  <label>Enter Length</label>
  <input (input)="onChangeLength($event.target.value)" />
</div>
```

Typescript code

```
  onChangeLength(value: string){

    const parsedValue = parseInt(value);

    if(!isNaN(parsedValue)){
      this.lenght = parsedValue;
    }

   }
```

Comment: Why not just use a reactive form and subscribe to the `valueChanges` of the field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular docs seem to suggest the way you are doing it is right:

You could try passing `$event` to the function and casting like they do:

```
onChangeLength(event: Event): string {
  const inputChangeValue = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
  // ...
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`event.target` is of type `EventTarget` which does not have the property `value`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget

You first need to cast the target to the appropriate HTML Element, which cannot be done in the template.

```html
<div>
  <label>Enter Length</label>
  <input (input)="onChangeLength($event.target)" />
</div>
```

```
onChangeLength(target: EventTarget){
  const input = target as HTMLInputElement;
  const value = input.value;
  ...
}
```