# Property name/value does not exist on type 'EventTarget & (HTMLInputElement | HTMLSelectElement)'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm seeing a Typescript error when trying to destruct `e.target` from both an `input` and `select` elements' `onChange` events. The errors are as follows

```
Property 'name' does not exist on type 'EventTarget & (HTMLInputElement | HTMLSelectElement)'.ts(2339)

Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget & (HTMLInputElement | HTMLSelectElement)'.ts(2339)
```

```
const handleChange = (
    e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLSelectElement>
  ) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    ...
    }
  )
...
return(
  <input
    name="category"
    value={formData.category}
    onChange={handleChange}
  />
  ...
  </input>
)
```

I've seen in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73557262/property-value-does-not-exist-on-type-eventtarget-in-angular) that adding a directive like below would fix the issue:

```js
/// <reference lib="dom" />
```

And indeed it does fix the issue with typescript but I would like to understand what is going on here and why that error is happening if the type seems to right?

My `tsconfig.json` looks like this:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleDetection": "force",
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "noEmit": true,
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "types": ["bun-types"],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", ".next/types/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```